# Is there function to get n-1 value from next row in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to get the date-1 value of next row date field. Need result similar to column "Expected Date".

[image]

I tried lag function but not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using hive `lead` function. Lead function give you the next row date value. Once you get the next row, use `date_add` or `date_sub` to subtract 1 day.

```
SELECT
Date,
coalesce(date_add(lead(Date,1) over(order by Date), -1),'9999-12-31') as expected_date
FROM
table
```

Finally, you can use `coalesce` to default the final row value to `9999-12-31` for the null row.

Comment: Thanks Rishu, I did this through lag function.